# Limit (epsilon-K)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If 
$$\lim(x_n) = x > 0$$ 
show that there exists a natural number K such that if $n \geq K$, then 
$$ \frac{1}{2}x < x_n < 2x$$

---

Using epsilon-K, what would the proof look like? 
I know that there exists a $K$ such that for all $n > K$
$$ |x_n - x| < \epsilon $$
We also know that:
$$ \frac{1}{2}x < x < 2x$$
Thus, can we say: there $\exists K$ such that for all $n > K$
$$ \frac{1}{2}x < x_n < 2x$$

Would this work? If so, where would I require more detail?

Comment: You’re definitely on the right track. By the definition of a limit, the sequence gets arbitrarily close to $x$ as $n$ becomes large. This means there also exists a $K$ such that ${1 \over 2} x < x_n < 2x$ for all $n \geq K$.

Comment: you might want set $\epsilon$ to a suitable value to obtain $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\lim x_n = x >0$ it follows that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $K\in \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $n>K$ $$|x_n-x|<\epsilon$$
Choose $\epsilon = \frac{x}{4}$. We can pick this because $x>0$. Now there is a $K$ in the natural numbers so that for all $n>K$ :
$$|x_n-x|<\frac{x}{4}$$
Thus $\frac{3}{4}x<x_n<\frac{5}{4}x$. It is now easy to see that $\frac{1}{2}x \leq \frac{3}{4}x<x_n<\frac{5}{4}x \leq 2x$

Comment: This seems reasonable. Are there any technicalities against setting $\epsilon$ to something that includes x?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very formal treatment with some comments. The limit definition
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0 : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N : |x_n - x| < \varepsilon$$
For all $\varepsilon > 0$ is key here. If for any positive real the above holds then in particular it will hold for
$$ \varepsilon_1 = x - \frac{1}{2}x, \ \varepsilon_2 = 2x - x$$
The limit statement above gives us the following
$$ \exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N_1 : |x_n - x| < \varepsilon_1$$
Writing this out, one finds that
$$ |x_n - x| < \varepsilon_1 = x - \frac{1}{2}x \implies x - x_n < x - \frac{1}{2}x \\$$
Here I have used the property $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} :|x| = |-x|$. So we get
$$ \forall n \geq N_1 : x_n > \frac{1}{2}x$$
The same analysis for $\varepsilon_2$ gives
$$  \exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N} : \forall n \geq N_2 : |x_n - x| < \varepsilon_2$$
Writing this out
$$|x_n - x| < 2x - x \implies x_n - x < 2x - x$$
From which we get
$$ \forall n \geq N_2 : x_n < 2x$$
Now we have two lower bounds $N_1$ and $N_2$. Naturally if we pick the larger of the two bounds we will inevitably capture the other bound as well! Indeed if $N_1$ were the larger bound, then if we choose $n \geq N_1$ we would also have $n \geq N_1 \geq N_2$. If we chose the smaller bound, then we might end up with a situation where the "intermediate" $n$ do not satisfy the inequality! So we denote
$$ K = \max \{ N_1, N_2 \}$$
Now we have that 
$$ \forall n \geq K : \frac{1}{2}x < x_n < 2x$$
As desired!